# css - twitter bootstrap fluid row shifted down because of float-left div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a two column layout. First column with fixed width, second one fluid. Which can be done in this way and works fine with regular content.

```
.left {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:gray;
}
.right {
    background-color:red;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/T7S3k/1/

**Problem**

When it comes to the point that I need bootstrap fluid rows on the right column, following problem occurs. Not the first `row-fluid` but the rest are shifted down right below the left column.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/fUwAr/

I can fix it by wrapping another span12

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ergec/KZ7vC/

But why I have to wrap it in another extra span12?